# How does HTTP/TCP match up request/respond on parallel transactions

Tags: sockets, http, networking, tcp, network-programming

Given an application does three HTTP requests to a server, same endpoint, same method and the server processes these requests in a different order, hence responses come in, in a different order than they were transmitted, how does it know which responds belongs to which request?

```
A:  GET /performAction
B:  GET /performAction
C:  GET /performAction
```

and the server responds in the order: `B, C, A`

Looking at the TCP/HTTP header my best guess is a combination of `TCP source port` and `sequence number`. But It would use one TCP connection, so I guess it comes down to the sequence number?

Comment: You can't send parallel requests over a single TCP connection. They would be sequentialized. *Ergo* if you have parallel requests they must be over separate TCP connections, which is sufficient to disambiguate them.

Comment: @EJP and how would they be disambiguated then? Through the internal source port?

Comment: They are arriving via separate TCP sockets, and possibly being handled by separate threads. No need for the application to inspect the source port.

Comment: @EJP I don't want to inspect. I meant how does the network layer figure that out.

Comment: It looks at the source and target addresses and ports in the TCP header and despatches the packet to the appropriate socket receive buffer. But your question was about how the application does it, and/or how HTTP does it, and the answer to that is that they don't.

Comment: @EJP: "*You can't send **parallel** requests over a single TCP connection*" - that is true in HTTP 1.1 and earlier, where requests **must** be replied to in the same order they are received. However, requests can be **pipelined** over a single connection allowing multiple requests can be in-flight at the same time without using separate connections, though the server must still process them sequentially.

Comment: @EJP: HTTP 2.0, on the other hand, is **designed for parallelism**, allowing multiple requests on the same connection to be processed asynchronously and replied to out-of-order. Responses are matched to requests using stream IDs and frame IDs in the HTTP payloads.